# Knockout js data grid formatting according to row values

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using knockout js grid,I used same way this example demonstrates.http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/.

How can I changed the cell color according value,

```
var initialData = [
    { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
    { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
    { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
    { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.addItem = function() {
        this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
    };

    this.sortByName = function() {
        this.items.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
        });
    };

    this.jumpToFirstPage = function() {
        this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
    };

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
            { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
        ],
        pageSize: 4
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));


<div class='liveExample'> 

    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

    <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
        Add item
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
        Sort by name
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
        Jump to first page
    </button>

</div>
```

1. I want to change cell color according to the "Seat
   Count" if seat count greater than 100 sell color should be "green"
2. need to add click event to grid rows

Can I do these things in this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, the **gridViewModel** binding-handler is presented only as a tutorial and not intended to be used as a fully-functional grid plugin, that is probably why they didn't bother add bindings for `css`, `style` and `click` handlers.

Yet, you can still add those missing handlers yourself (change **line 51** in `knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js`):

```
<td data-bind=\"text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText], click: typeof click == 'function' ? click : function(){}, style: typeof style == 'function' ? style($parent) : {} \"></td>\
```

Then using it as follows:

```
this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name", click: function() { alert('clicked'); } },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales", style: function(item) { if (item.sales>100) return { color: 'green' } } },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
```